# Pandas column for sequence of variable

Tags: pandas

I'd like help creating a new column in Pandas that indicates whether something happened before or after in a sequence. I've included a description of the problem and a small sample of the dataframe as a dictionary below.

The dataframe is a list of interventions that happen to users as a "text" or a "call". Each row is an intervention. So, for instance, User122 had two calls and then a text (indicated in the sequence column).

I'd like a new column that specifies whether an intervention happened before or after the first instance of a call. So, for user122, there would be three rows in a new column, "text_after_call" that would be an Series of something like 'before, before, after', because the first instance of a text is in sequence 3, and calls where sequence 1 and 2. If a user has no text or call associated with it, the value would be NaN.

I think the solution would involve creating a loop through each user and checking whether the row with the first instance of "text" is greater or less than the sequence of last 'call', but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated and let me know if I can make this question any easier to answer!

```
{'sequence': {0: 1.0,
  1: 2.0,
  2: 3.0,
  3: 1.0,
  4: 1.0,
  5: 2.0,
  6: 1.0,
  7: 2.0,
  8: 3.0},
 'text_or_call': 
 {0: call,
  1: call,
  2: text,
  3: text,
  4: text,
  5: nan,
  6: text,
  7: call,
  8: call},
 'user': {0: 'user122',
  1: 'user122',
  2: 'user122',
  3: 'user124',
  4: 'user125',
  5: 'user125',
  6: 'user126',
  7: 'user126',
  8: 'user126'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to specify if `texts` are before or after the first `call` of a user, first we have to find the index of the first call for each `user`.

```
first_call_index = df.groupby(['user']).apply(lambda x: np.min((x.loc[x['text_or_call'] == 'call']).index))
```

This yields a `dataframe` containing the index of each users' first call. We can `merge` this with our original `dataframe` on `user`.

```
df_index = df.merge(first_call_index.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'first_call_index'}))
```

Afterwards we can just compare the index of each row with the value in the `first_call_index` row and test if the current row is a `text` message. If the index of the current row is before the `first_call_index` we set the value to `before`, if the other way around, we set the value to `after`.

```
df_index.loc[(df_index['first_call_index'] < df_index.index) & (df_index['text_or_call'] == 'text'), 'text_after_call'] = 'After'
df_index.loc[(df_index['first_call_index'] > df_index.index) & (df_index['text_or_call'] == 'text'), 'text_after_call'] = 'Before'
```

**Result**

```
sequence    text_or_call    user    first_call_index    text_after_call
0   1.0     call            user122     0.0             NaN
1   2.0     call            user122     0.0             NaN
2   3.0     text            user122     0.0             After
3   1.0     text            user124     NaN             NaN
4   1.0     text            user125     NaN             NaN
5   2.0     NaN             user125     NaN             NaN
6   1.0     text            user126     7.0             Before
7   2.0     call            user126     7.0             NaN
8   3.0     call            user126     7.0             NaN
```